# Unable to connect to Cloud MySQL from GCP Cloud Run using Unix sockets

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

My Cloud Run project (Python/Flask) is able to connect to my Cloud MySQL instance correctly over TCP (locally and when using `gcloud` beta code dev environment). However I am unable to connect via Unix socket, which is required when deployed to Google Cloud Platform.

I've followed the ['Connecting from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL'](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) guide as closely as possible.

Both are in the same region, and I believe that the IAM permissions are set correctly (**mycompute@developer.gserviceaccount.com** member has both '**Cloud SQL Client**' and '**Cloud SQL Admin**' roles). I've added the IP address for my Cloud Run app (as determined by pinging the app URL) to the Cloud SQL instance '**Authorized Networks**'.

I don't see any related DB errors or log messages in GCP logging.

I've added considerable logging around the point that I initialize the connection, and have determined that connection fails when I attempt db.connect() (see code snippet), and skips the `with` body (i.e. I only get logging 1 and logging 6 messages), and doesn't raise an exception. `init_connection_engine()` and `init_unix_connection_engine(db_config)` are unchanged from Google's sample code.

```
def create_tables():
  global db
  db = db or init_connection_engine()
  # logging 1
  
  try:
    with db.connect() as conn:
      # logging 2
      conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calendars "
        "( team_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, calendar_id VARCHAR(200), owner_email VARCHAR(50), calendar_name VARCHAR(100), timezone VARCHAR(50), uuid VARCHAR(50), refresh_token VARCHAR(500), PRIMARY KEY (team_id));"
      )
      # logging 3

      conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events "
        "( event_id VARCHAR(200), team_id VARCHAR(50), task_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(200), "
        "location VARCHAR(300), details VARCHAR(500), start DATETIME, end DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (task_id) );"
      )

      # logging 4
  except Exception as e:
    # logging 5
  # logging 6
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I try db.connect() by itself (not using with), then I get the following error: 

(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)"

Comment: 1) Show the Cloud Run deploy command. 2) Show the connection code. 3) **localhost** is not a Unix socket. Edit your question with these details.

Comment: Update: a colleague helped me resolve this issue. I needed to explicitly add the Cloud SQL instance in my Cloud Run service's 'connections' tab. Step 2 under 'Configuring Cloud Run' in their documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run